# Newly added data from Database not showing on ComboBox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

Please help when i insert a new data to the database it is not showing in the comboBox unless i restart the program. Is something missing from this ?

```
        CmbSupp.Items.Clear();
        con.Open();
        Refresh();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select SupplierName from SuppTbl";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dp.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            CmbSupp.Items.Add(dr["SupplierName"].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
```

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Did you debug this? did you test the same method with just dummy values in yoru combobox?, do you check to see if `dr["SupplierName"]` has any data? did you check to see if the query returns anything? If you could work things like this out your self, then your question would not be a broad statement like "*my Newly added data from Database not showing on ComboBox*" it would be more like "*my combo box isnt updating*", or "*my query isnt returning data*", ect ect ect

Comment: you could try to use your Refresh() after the for-each loop so it refreshes after data has been added

Comment: could you please add your `Refresh()` method?

Comment: I tested your code which works fine. Are you sure the method of above code called after you add the new row?

Comment: why ExecuteNonQuery if you are returning the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`CmbSupp.Items.Clear()`
To `CmbSupp.Items = null;`
this is a small Bug,You have to set Null Value and Reset Data;
Try It;

Comment: CmbSupp.Items = null; seems to give me redline for some reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void RefreshData()
{
    dt.Clear();
    con.Open();
    Refresh();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select SupplierName from SuppTbl";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    dp.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
}

private void BindToComboBox()
{
    CmbSupp.DataSource = dt;
    CmbSupp.ValueMember = "SupplierName";
    CmbSupp.DisplayMember = "SupplierName";
}
```

Ideally, you include the table's ID and put it in ValueMember property. You call the Bind ToComboBox once and just call RefreshData() when there's changes in the database. It should automatically update the contents of the combobox.